# Crash only in release when having #if Debug in a specific place. Very strange

Tags: ios, swift

I developed my app in debug mode, and was running successfully with out any problem. Then when I switch to release mode, it crashed on the part where I ask it to download the image from the network. XCode is telling me about bad_Access and give me a stack but I cannot really understand it.

So I did some research on this problem. Many people are saying about blocks not retain in stack or having weak pointers. Then I go and comment each part of my code to see which code is causing this crash.

Then it surprised me so much that when I quote the code below like so, it solved the problem.

[image]

This is a helper function that I wrote to only print the log msg in debug build.

I have no idea why this happened.

I also tried to call this print Msg anywhere else inside my app, and that does not cause any of the crash at all.

Here is a detailed description on where I used this macro and caused crash.

I have a network manager class, in that class it has static function that call alamofire API to fetch the JSON file. The static class has a complete parameter that accepts a block that called when alamofire finished its job. Within that complete block, I created each item objects using that JSON file(contains array). After created the item with in the same block, I call another function that calls another static method in network manager class to download the image from an url that I got in JSON file. before calling that static method, I use printMsg to print out that I am going to download the image and that is where it crashes because of #if DEBUG

I was first think that probably I should not call that static method inside networkManger to download the image, but the problem is the #if used in print function that shocks me.

So my question is why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tired moving all that code into the completion block itself without the function?

Comment: @lostAtSeaJoshua No, I haven't. I will go and try it on Tuesday

Comment: @lostAtSeaJoshua Very strange. Seems like the problem goes away after the thanksgiving long weekend. It didn't crash anymore when I call this function. I promise I didn't nothing at all for solving this problem.

Comment: One of those ghost bugs, they happen from time to time. Glad to hear it is working as expected. @JerryShan